# How to get control id from its handle?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

How would one get an id of a control given its handle?

I want to set a tooltip on ListView control's header. As far as I figured out I need an id of the control to which I want to add this tooltip. As described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298368%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, [`GetDlgCtrlID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645478(v=vs.85).aspx).

Note that the sample you linked to immediately converts the toolID back to a handle again making your call redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method I wrote for that:

```
// get identifier to a window
void showWindowID(HWND windowTarget) {
    int theID = GetDlgCtrlID(windowTarget);

    wchar_t text_buffer[100] = { 0 }; 

    // convert
    swprintf(text_buffer, _countof(text_buffer), L"%d", theID); 

    // print to console
    //OutputDebugString(text_buffer); 

    // output result to a messagebox
    MessageBox(nullptr, text_buffer, L"The ID", MB_OK);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `ListView_GetHeader()` to get the `HWND` of the ListView's Header control (which would be the replacement for the `GetDlgItem()` call in the sample you linked to).  You do not need to get the Header's Control ID.

Comment: If you are writing a custom provider which returns Control ID it is not useful to say "You don't need Control ID". Please, answer the question.